# Java.util.Scanner to int

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

How can I get the number stored on "dryrun.txt" to be set as int url? I know this is a very simple answer but I can't seem to get it. I've seen other posts about using parseInt but when I do I always get an error and I asked my teacher and he said that that is only used to look for numbers within other text, in this file its just 1 number. Thank you for your help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Even
{
  public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    int even = 0;
    int url = 0;
    int Counter = 2;
    Scanner fileScan;

    fileScan = new Scanner (new File("dryrun.txt"));
    url = fileScan.nextInt();

    if ( url > 2)
      System.out.println ("Error");      
    if (url % 2 == 0)
      even = (Counter + 2);

    System.out.print(" "+ even +" "); 
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the value in the file?

Comment: This code seems about right.  What is the error you're getting?

Comment: Im not getting any error, but nothing I have works, if i set the value in the file to 2, it should print out Error but it doesn't, it just adds 2 to it and prints 4 out. How can I the value in the file to be the int url?

Comment: The `url > 2` means greater than 2 so if your file value is 2 then it will not pass that if statement. Getting an output of 4 for an input of 2 is the expected result. You can test it by going `System.out.println(url);` after you read the value in at `url = fileScan.nextInt();`

Comment: Okay, yeah you're right sorry I didn't realize that but anyway I still have my original problem, the value in the file is 0 now and it gives me the Error but if I set it to 2 it adds four and doesn't give me the error..

Comment: `if url > 2` print error `if url % 2 == 0` add 2, so when `url == 4` you will hit both case...use and `if-else` statement...

Comment: @user1101495 What's the error when the value in the file is 0? Your question doesn't explain alot. Edit your question.

Comment: What are the expected inputs and expected results?

Answer (score 1):

> Okay, yeah you're right sorry I didn't realize that but anyway I still
>   have my original problem, the value in the file is 0 now and it gives
>   me the Error but if I set it to 2 it adds four and doesn't give me the
>   error..

This would suggest that your logic is wrong...

Based on this code, lets do some desk checking...

```
if ( url > 2)
  System.out.println ("Error");      
if (url % 2 == 0)
  even = (Counter + 2);
```

Assuming `url == 4`...

- `if (url > 2)` = `if (4 > 2)` = `true`, print `Error`
- `if (url % 2 == 0)` = `if (4 % 2 == 0)` = `true`, `even = Counter + 2`

Assuming `url == 2`...

- `if (url > 2)` = `if (2 > 2)` = `false`, do nothing...
- `if (url % 2 == 0)` = `if (2 % 2 == 0)` = `true`, `even = Counter + 2`

Assuming you want to print an error when the number is over `1` you should use `if (url >= 2)` or `if (url > 1)`

Assuming you don't want to continue calculating the result when you have an error, you should use an `if-else` statement, along the lines of...

```
if ( url > 2)
  System.out.println ("Error");      
else if (url % 2 == 0) {
  even = (Counter + 2);
  System.out.print(" " + even + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    int even = 0;
    int url = 0;
    int Counter = 2;
    Scanner fileScan;

    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\dryrun.txt"));
    fileScan = new Scanner(in);
    while (fileScan.hasNextLine()) {
        url = Integer.parseInt(fileScan.nextLine()); //
    }

    if (url > 2)
        System.out.println("Error");
    if (url % 2 == 0)
        even = (Counter + 2);

    System.out.print(" " + even + " ");

}
```